# Pass in generic type to internal function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write this function:

```js
export default function generateServerSideProps<SearchResponse>(mode: Mode) {
  return async ({ query }: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const { query: searchQuery } = query;
    const makePath = buildMakePathFromMode(mode, searchQuery, filters);
    return {
      props: {
        mode,
        searchQuery,
        filters,
        initialData: await firstPage<SearchResponse>(makePath),
      },
    };
  }
}
```

`firstPage` calls an api and receives a response. I want to pass in the response type, however typescript is seeing an error on `searchReponse` in the line `initialData: await firstPage<SearchResponse>(makePath)`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you pls provide the error message

Comment: Hi! What is the error? Is firstPage a gerneric functiion? Can you show us firstPage as well?

Comment: Please show the code of `firstPage` and what the error of typescript. You should make sure that `firstPage` is a generic function from the current situation.

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9rRm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: Unfortunately no one can help you without more information.  Most likely you need to put some constraint on the generic `SearchResponse` like `<SearchResponse extends SomeBaseType>`.